# Three.js - draw circle on a sphere

Tags: 3d, three.js, line, polygons

I am very new to Three.js and I am just practicing with geometries.
Now I want to plot polygonal lines in 3D geometry.
Suppose I have the 3D coordinates of a polygonal line, already stored as an array of THREE.Vector3 objects and all points being located inside the unit cube (1,1,1).
How to draw the polygonal line from such array, in 3D and using Three.js ?
(I didn't find anywhere one such tutorial and I think that a response with a sketch of code would be very helpful to many)

Comment: Is that what you mean ? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Line

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out this week and let you know. Anybody else's observations are welcomed for this (not so popular) topic.